# How to insert a element into a LinkedList of the std::collections::LinkedList library in rust

Tags: algorithm, performance, rust, rust-tokio

```rust
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
  let mut list = LinkedList::<String>::new();
  
  // Looking for something like insert(value, index)

}
```

I want a function that inserts the given value at the given index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See at54321's answer for a discussion on whether inserting into a `LinkedList` is a good idea in the first place (probably not).

Now, if you are sure you want to perform that operation, you can write it yourself by combining the [`LinkedList::split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.split_off), [`LinkedList::push_back`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.push_back) and [`LinkedList::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.append) methods:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn insert_at(l: &mut LinkedList<u8>, idx: usize, val: u8) {
    let mut tail = l.split_off(idx);
    l.push_back(val);
    l.append(&mut tail);
}

fn main(){
    let mut l = LinkedList::from([1, 2, 3]);

    insert_at(&mut l, 2, 4);
    
    let res: Vec<u8> = l.into_iter().collect();
    assert_eq!(res, vec![1, 2, 4, 3]);
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bf73359121232757a0251150636c7a9)

Comment: Is this costly? Does it create two separate List and increase memory usage?

Comment: No, it works as if you were to implement an optimized version by hand pretty much. `split_off` takes *O(n)*, having to iterate to the node where the split happens, `push_back` takes *O(1)*, as `LinkedList` is a doubly linked list (pointers to the first and last elements are stored) and `append` takes *O(1)* as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an element at a certain position (index), then you most probably are using the wrong data structure.

The only way to do that would to be to start iterating from the beginning and count the number of elements. However, that can have a negative performance impact, potentially comparable to that of inserting an element into a [`Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html).

The main benefit of using a linked list is fast insertion/deletion of an element. But if you need to traverse many elements in order to find a certain position, that's probably going to take significantly more time than the insert itself. With vectors, inserting (not appending at the end) would be slower, but finding an element by index is an instantaneous operation (no need to *traverse* elements to get there).

Comment: Insertion and deletion in Vec is O(N) but access is O(1).
In LinkedList insertion and deletion is O(1) but we just need to iterate through the content to get there. If there were like a million elements in Vec and LinkedList which do you think has less time for insertion.

Comment: @Fanisus, I understand your point, but you shouldn't assume reading will *always* be faster than writing. For example, if LinkedList nodes are scattered in memory, that could lead to significantly more cache misses. There are a few more important factors, that could affect the scanning speed, as well as the array-copy speed. That's why I didn't want to specifically compare the time to scan a LL with the time to insert in a vector. The point was rather not to underestimate the time to scan a LL.